# Creating a solid color header with a centered div inside

Tags: css, html

Here's what I'm aiming for, working 100% correctly in `Firefox 7`.

[image]

When I open it in `IE 8`, it displays like this:

[image]

Here's the basic layout:

```
<div id="header-home">
    <div id="header-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

With all of the elements inside of the `#header-content`.

Here's the relevant HTML and CSS hosted on JSFiddle. If you stretch the preview pane you'll see the contents are centered correctly on Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/stapiagutierrez/agURs/

Why is IE not centering the div as it should?

Comment: Can you show us full code? One of possible reasons why "margin: auto" is not working is that you don't have doctype or have a wrong one.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov The entire code is in the JSFiddle link. I notice I'm missing a doctype. What should I use then? Why is IE so finnicky! :(

Comment: Well, you use xhtml, so i added xhtml one to JSFiddle. Try with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/agURs/1/

Comment: It seems the problem was I was missing a Doctype. Put it in as your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE falling back to quirks mode if you don't have doctype in your html. And in quirks mode margin auto; didn't works.

Adding doctype can solve it.

Right doctype and header for xhtml (so xml-readers can understand that it is xml and can parse it) is:

```
<?xml version="1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

But if you place xml line before DOCTYPE line, IE will not accept it (as it thinks that doctype is always first line of document). So to make it work in IE you should write:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?xml version="1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

or just:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `margin:0 auto` to `#header-content`.